# Overrunning buffer issue while passing array value to another function

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I wrote a function to pass a wide character array to another function . After running the analysis report i am getting following error

```
Overrunning array "array" of 12 bytes by passing it to a function which accesses it at byte offset 130.
```

**My logic :**

```
static char array[6];

function1()
{
    (void) memset(&array, 0, sizeof(array));
    (void)swprintf(array, 6,get_wide_char((void *)"%0d"),  40);
    function2(array);
}

function2(char* value)
{

}
```

Here size of char is 1 byte and array size is 6 . my first question is how it is taking Overrunning array "array" of 12 bytes ? Any solution to this issue . or anything i am missing here ? Any suggestion ?

Comment: Two notes: Please specify *the* programming language and clean up the code, e.g. avoiding macros and resolving aliases to make it clear. Oh, and avoid casts and turn on compiler warnings, too!

Comment: What is `get_wide_char`? If you turn on warnings, you will see that: 1. You should add explicit return types on the functions 2. you are missing a forward-declaration of `function2`. 3. You are passing an incompatible pointer type to `swprintf`.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a pointer to a 6-element `char` array to `swprintf`, which expects a `wchar_t` pointer as first argument and the number of characters (not bytes) to write as second argument.

`wchar_t` is likely larger than `char`, probably `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2`. Therefore the buffer passed as first argument should have at least size `sizeof(wchar_t)*6` (probably `12`). This is not the case (`sizeof(char)` is always `1`, so `sizeof(array) == 6`) and so you have a buffer overflow.

Don't mix `char` and `wchar_t` operations. Either use `wchar_t` and `swprintf` together or use `char` and `sprintf` together.

Enable warnings (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` on gcc/clang) and follow up on each of them. The problem would be easy to spot this way:

```
<source>:11:20: warning: passing argument 1 of 'swprintf' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     (void)swprintf(array, 6,get_wide_char((void *)"%0d"),  40);
                    ^~~~~
```